# Why is sending an email using Indy10 and OpenSSL using TLS 1.0 despite me specifying TLS 1.2?

Tags: delphi, openssl, tls1.2, indy, indy10

I am using Delphi 10.4.2, Indy 10.6.2.0, and OpenSSL DLL versions 1.0.2u. I am trying to add email notifications to a very large existing product. I first created an email class in a sample project and it works perfectly. I then added the class to our existing product and I get either a "SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:unknown protocol" error or a "ssl3_get_record:wrong version number" error (depending on how I tweak the values). The code is identical in both projects, and I have made sure multiple times that I have the same DLL files in both project folders.

After using Wireshark to search for the issue, I found out that when I send it from my test project, it successfully uses TLS1.2, but when I send it from our existing product, it for some reason uses TLS1.0 just for the Client Hello handshake. Here's the output:

[image]

My code looks like this (although I've tweaked it a million times with other values):

[image]

I do have older versions of the OpenSSL DLL files on my machine in various locations, but the versions in the project folder are definitely the newest one. This project is very large and uses a ton of different Runtime Packages/3rd party components and such that might influence this somehow.

I'm currently at a loss as to what could be causing this though. Why would the same exact code with the same DLL's in the project folder behave differently? Is there somewhere else that Delphi might look first for DLL files? Or could another Unit or component somehow be pulling in an older version of OpenSSL? Is there a practical way to debug this issue?

Comment: Use [Process Explorer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/process-explorer) to see which DLLs from where in which version actually loaded. Avoid screenshots of source code, because nobody will re-type it when trying to reconstruct your issue - you're just shooting your foot doing this.

Comment: FYI: Indy has an `OpenSSLVersion()` function in the `IdSSLOpenSSL` unit, so you can see which version was actually loaded. And, using the `GetSSLLibHandle()` and `GetCryptLibHandle()` functions from the `IdSSLOpenSSLHeaders` unit, you can use Microsoft's `GetModuleFileName()` API to get the paths of the DLLs that were actually loaded. Also, Indy has a `IdOpenSSLSetLibPath()` function in the `IdSSLOpenSSLHeaders` unit, if you need to specify the exact folder path that Indy should load the DLLs from.